# Problemas al interpretar archivos html

Tags: html

Buenas tardes comunidad,

En este momento tengo un problema con el llamado de algunos archivos html y la verdad no tengo ni idea de que pueda ser.

Tengo dos archivos llamados desde diferentes carpetas dentro de la carpeta raiz de apache, en una carpeta el archivo html me abre sin problemas y el otro solo me muestra el codigo html ¿A que creen que se deba tal situación?

El codigo esta solo esto, en ambos archivos:

```html
<pre>
<p>Hola Mundo</p>
</pre>
```

Link que interpreta:
https://www.midominio.net/admin/gabriel.html

Link que no interpreta:
https://www.midominio.net/rsarchivos/gabriel.html

Comment: Hola Luis, podría poner código de lo que haces y como las llamas desde html , quizá sería problema de rutas no sabemos, por eso es necesario completar mas esa pregunta , mira [ask] para más información.Saludos.

Comment: voy a editar mi html y colocaré dos rutas.

Comment: Listo coloque un ejemplo sencillo con una edición simple en html

Comment: Según veo, tienes una etiqueta llamada `<pre></pre>`, esta hace que todo lo que está dentro se muestre tal cual o sea no va ha interpretar el html , revisa eso.

Comment: Ya veo donde esta, pero como puedo eso llamarse en archivo que no estoy invocando ningun otro?

Comment: No he entendido tu último comentario, ¿a que te refieres?

Comment: Cree ese archivo y solo agregue <p>Hola Mundo<p>. No agregue mas etiquetas, como se pudo agregar la etiqueta <pre> si yo en ningun momento la agregue.

Comment: A lo mejor se te habrá pasado, o escribiste p en el editor de texto y se te completó como pre y no te diste cuenta, pero lo importante es que has encontrado el error gracias a Sebastián y ya puedes solucionarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, si ya encontré el problema por eso le vote a Sebastian, pero como les comento si le das ver codigo fuente puedes ver que no hay una etiqueta pre agregado por ningun lado pero si le das inspeccionar si te aparece, no entiendo porque razon lo hace ya que no lo agregue y no solo me ocurre con ese archivo me ocurre con todos.

Comment: aplicando el codigo css del pre por mi propia cuenta no muestra el codigo html del archivo que estoy probando, no creo que sea el pre que este forzando el muestreo del codigo. Incluso he editado mi post, ejecuto el codigo y pesar de que tiene las etiquetas pre, este se muestra correctamente.

Comment: El pre funciona es para decirle al codigo en tome en cuenta los espacios en blanco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo el problema ocurría porque tenia un archivo .htaccess guardado y oculto en las rutas donde el código se veía afectado. Lo único que hice fue eliminar dicho archivo y el problema se solventó.